# XFCE 4.12.5 in Debaian 10 no wallpaper

Tags: debian, xfce, wallpaper

I updated from Debian 9 to 10, and now I can't configure XFCE 4.12.5 to show wallpapers/background pics from a certain folder. The folder contains the pics I expect to be there. I tried to configure this via the Settings-Desktop dialog, as well as right clicking on a single pic and choose it as background. Nothing happens, my desktop stays gray.

Comment: The following are Xubuntu-related, but they may offer some ideas: https://askubuntu.com/questions/563491/gray-desktop-after-updating-xfce-on-xubuntu and https://askubuntu.com/questions/266271/error-parsing-gtk-icon-sizes-string-desktop-grey-with-no-icons

Comment: Yep, "Set as wallpaper" in thunar seems broken, but changing the location of the background images folder in the Desktop Settings (don't try to choose an image here) and then clicking on one of the preview images works as expected here.

Comment: I'll try it next weekend, when I'm sitting in front of this computer again. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you could try installing hsetroot if it's not already installed

Comment: install it how? and use it how?